# Where to find list of Tensorflow pretrained models available in download.tensorflow.org/models

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, inception

I am trying the find the pretrained models (graph.pd and labels.txt) files for Tensorflow (for all of the Inception versions and MobileNet)

After much searching I found some models in, https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models

like, https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip

https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_dec_2015.zip

But I found this as links from various blogs/etc. But is there a way to list all the models/zips in this dir? https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models

I want the latest of Inceptionv3 and MobileNet, does anyone know the file names in models for these?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the models hosted on [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models) are not listed anywhere publically (or at least my research failed!). However, there are official and several nonofficial [GitHub](https://github.com/topics/pretrained-models) repositories with high-level TensorFlow model definitions and pretrained weights. For example:

- [Nonofficial](https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch): that includes **NASNet**, **ResNeXt**, **ResNet**, **InceptionV4**, **InceptionResnetV2**, **Xception**, **DPN** (need PyTorch).
- [Official](https://github.com/tensorflow/models): contains a wide range of official and research models such as **resnet**, **wide-deep**, **inception**, **delf**, and **tcn**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. For https://github.com/tensorflow/models this does not contain the .pb and labels files, only the checkpoint files for building or retraining. At least this is my understanding? These files are not useful at runtime, only for training your own next, or would take many hours/days of processing to generate the .pb and labels files. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

[This page on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) is my "go to" page to find the pretrained models that I think you are looking for including .pb files:

Comment: The link is out of date. [Here's a link to tensorflow v2 models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/fab47e9e105d3cc98fc04cf172fa2038607d0939/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).